# Connect Google Cloud SQL Potsgres with Google DataStudio

Tags: google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

I am wondering whats the best way to connect my google cloud sql postgres DB with data studio.

I do not see a google connector for cloud sql posgres, but only for cloud sql mysql in datastudio. There is a generic postgres connector, but I am not sure if this should be the way to go or if I should first transfer my data to google bigquery and then connect it to data studio.

Any idea's whats the best way?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Sadly, a Cloud SQL connector doesn't exist and you need to use the public IP to reach it and to grant network on your instance. I didn't try, but you can try to use BigQuery federated queries, but it will increase the latency in data recovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to *Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL* using *Data Studio*.

For that, follow the official Data Studio [documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010) for connecting to PostgreSQL:

1. **Sign in** to Data Studio.
2. In the top left, click **Create**, then select **Data Source**.
3. Select the **PostgreSQL** connector.
4. Configure access to your database using one of the [connection options](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010#basic).
5. Click **AUTHENTICATE**. You will see a list of tables in that database.
6. Select a table.
7. Click **CONNECT**.

---

**NOTE:**
In order to *authenticate* after the *4th step*, you will also need to open access to the following [IP addresses](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010#notes) so that Data Studio can access your database:

> 64.18.0.0/20
>
> 64.233.160.0/19
>
> 66.102.0.0/20
>
> 66.249.80.0/20
>
> 72.14.192.0/18
>
> 74.125.0.0/16
>
> 108.177.8.0/21
>
> 173.194.0.0/16
>
> 207.126.144.0/20
>
> 209.85.128.0/17
>
> 216.58.192.0/19
>
> 216.239.32.0/19

You can do that for your Cloud SQL instance either through the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ip#add) or using the gcloud command:

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --authorized-networks=[IP_ADDR1],[IP_ADDR2]...
```

Comment: The IP address list now includes an IPv6 IP which you can't add to the Cloud SQL list.  Can you confirm you are able to connect still?  I can't connect to my Postgres cloud SQL instance with Data Studio even with all these IPs in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pull simple dataset directly from your postgres database, you can connect to Data Studio by using generic **postgres connector** and allow public ip to authorize by following this [google instruction](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010).

On the other hand, if you want to query large dataset for reporting, **BigQuery** will be best suited as it's perfect for querying large dataset quickly and storing for the analytics.

Pricing wise for the long run, you can compare the pricing of [Cloud Sql](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing) and [Big Query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) as they are priced differently.

Querying data from cloud sql through BigQuery's federated query and explore it to data studio without storing dataset in BigQuery is not a recommended way for large dataset as it will increase the latency for your report.

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this - I think there is something wrong with adding authorised networks IP addresses for your instance in google console. I named each address ds1, ds2 etc. and had to add them one by one. Adding all 12 then clicking 'save' didn't seem to save them.

Even when I had them all listed in console, it would not authenticate.

As a last gasp attempt I tried a v12 instance (was on v14) but made no difference.

Finally I ran the IP updates as a gcloud command:

gcloud sql instances patch [instance] --authorized-networks=64.18.0.0/20,64.233.160.0/19,66.102.0.0/20,66.249.80.0/20,72.14.192.0/18,74.125.0.0/16,108.177.8.0/21,173.194.0.0/16,207.126.144.0/20,209.85.128.0/17,216.58.192.0/19,216.239.32.0/19

This then let me in but only on the v12 instance.

In summary, stick to v12 and run a gcloud command above... Crazy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Skyvia connector for cloud data: https://skyvia.com/connect/google-data-studio. Skyvia connector for Google Data Studio uses Skyvia Connect SQL endpoints as an intermediate layer to convert SQL queries into native data source API calls for querying data. In my case, it took no more than 5 minutes to connect.